# simply use "setContentView" or "startActivity"?

Tags: android

I'm learning android and in a tutorial, to open a new screen they use

...

```
startActivity( new Intent("com.rob.minispy.sweet"));
```

( in main.java )

...

```
public class sweet extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    }

}
```

( in sweet.java )

...

and finally

```
<activity android:name=".sweet"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SWEET" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

( in the manifest )

now not only that it doesn't really work and make the app crash, wouldn't it be easier to do it simply by

```
setContentView(R.layout.splash);
```

from main.java or are there some downsides to that?

Thanks!

Comment: You could have given a link to the tutorial to make things more clear. In any case I would recommend learning android from developers site.

Comment: sure: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ceWhhyQt-MU&feature=related

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android setContentView or Intents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191997/android-setcontentview-or-intents)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 ways to start the `sweet` activity

1. Change `startActivity( new Intent("com.rob.minispy.sweet"));` to `startActivity( new Intent("android.intent.action.SWEET"));` See more info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28java.lang.String%29)
2. `startActivity(new Intent(this,sweet.class))`; . This uses the form `Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)`. More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29)

Comment: thanks! "startActivity(new Intent(this,sweet.class));" worked! :) but still, why should I start a new activity, if I can simply use setContentView ?

Comment: Well, you may need to initialize some stuff when displaying your layout (data from db for example). So by starting a new activity, you can implement this in `onCreate`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's best to start a new activity because this way Android will automatically handle transitions from one activity to another. Your application crashes because you do it improperly. Intent should be created as `new Intent(this, com.rob.minispy.sweet.class)`. You use a string in the constructor which is supposed to be an action and not a class.